# Is there any way to make notification about current user with writing access in excel file

Tags: vba, excel

Everyone knows that default (in-build) Excel notification about current user with writing access to excel file (at server with access from multiple users) DOES NOT WORK properly. It means, when someone tries to open some excel file which is already opened by someone else, Excel sometimes only says that the file is opened by another user without his identification.

To correct this wrong behavior of excel, one can write code as follows:

```
Sub auto_open()
  Dim fso As FileSystemObject: Set fso = New FileSystemObject
  Dim strPath As String: strPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\writer.txt"
  If Not ActiveWorkbook.ReadOnly Then
    Dim oFile As Object: Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile(strPath)
    oFile.WriteLine Environ("username")
    oFile.Close
    Set oFile = Nothing
  ElseIf Dir(strPath) <> "" Then
    Dim txtStream As Object: Set txtStream = fso.OpenTextFile(strPath, ForReading, False)
    MsgBox "User " & txtStream.ReadLine & " has this file opened for writing."
    txtStream.Close
  End If
  Set fso = Nothing
End Sub

Sub auto_close()
  If Not ActiveWorkbook.ReadOnly Then
    Dim strPath As String: strPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\writer.txt"
    If Dir(strPath) <> "" Then
      Kill strPath
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

(while using "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" reference)

This all works well until you use old good .xls file. BUT once you start to use .xlsm modern format file, the auto_open subroutine is unfortunately not triggered in case that the second (the reading) user choose in the "File in use" warning message the "Notify" option. And thus once the first person leave the excel, the second gain the option to get the file for writing, but the text file with his username is not created (see the attached code) and thus the another user, opening the same excel file, will not know about current writing user.

Does anyone have please any idea how to correct this behavior in the .xlsm file? I guess the only way to correct it is to find out some subroutine, which is triggered once the user is reopening excel file for writing.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `ActiveWorkbook.ReadOnly` try this more direct approach - which from my experience over a network is much faster than opening the file to test it - code courtesy of [Bob Phillips](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=468)

```
Sub test() 
    If Not IsFileOpen("C:\yourfilehere.xls") Then 
        Workbooks.Open "C:\yourfilehere.xls" 
    End If 
End Sub 


Function IsFileOpen(FileName As String) 
    Dim iFilenum As Long 
    Dim iErr As Long 

    On Error Resume Next 
    iFilenum = FreeFile() 
    Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #iFilenum 
    Close iFilenum 
    iErr = Err 
    On Error Goto 0 

    Select Case iErr 
    Case 0:    IsFileOpen = False 
    Case 70:   IsFileOpen = True 
    Case Else: Error iErr 
    End Select 

End Function
```

Comment: I am sorry, but this answer is not related to my question. Probably I was not clear before. I do not want to open other file, in the subroutine auto_open I try to check if the file, which I already MANUALLY opened, is writable, or not. If it is writable I save the username to txt file. If it is only readable, I read the username from txt file. My question is towards the reopening version of AUTO_OPEN subroutine. The attached code here only presents something which is working in .xls world, and unfortunately not in .xlsm new world.

Comment: This code is related to your question. It checks if the file is writable *before* it is opened - which is quicker than opening and checking `readonly`. It works just as well with `xlsm` as `xls` files.

Comment: Ok, thank you, but I do not want to open other file from my excel file.